# How can I plot multiple splines when reading random data from txt files

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import spline
data = np.loadtxt('surging_data.txt', delimiter=',') 
x1=data[0:3,0]
y1=data[0:3,1]
x2=data[3:6,0]
y2=data[3:6,1]
x1_smooth = np.linspace(x1.min(),x1.max(),100)
y1_smooth = spline(x1,y1, x1_smooth)
x2_smooth = np.linspace(x2.min(),x2.max(),100)
y2_smooth = spline(x2,y2, x2_smooth)
plt.plot(x1_smooth,y1_smooth, marker= 'o',linestyle='solid', label='Exp 8-10')
plt.plot(x2_smooth,y2_smooth, marker='*', linestyle='solid', label='Exp 12-14')
```

My data is in the following format:

```
0.0917,2.500,0.210207685
0.9999,1.250,0.129627709
8.5916,0.500,0.078210543
0.1023,2.250,0.195346414
1.0230,1.000,0.103702167
8.0873,0.500,0.060291812
```

I am not able to plot the splines for my data which I have read from txt files. When I simply plot it using array function or otherwise read from txt, it works good, but when I use the spline function, it gave the different/wrong plot. I think I am not able to define the correct function for x-smooth in my code. I have tried from available answers, but couldn't find one when extracting data from txt files. I am a very new user, so it would be great to have some help.

[image]

My actual plot is the one on left which is correct, but the one on the right is not correct after I try to draw the splines.

Comment: Not enough information.  Please post the array returned by ```spline``` and point out to us why you think it is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe someone can correct me but the default order for the spline function is three and if I remember correctly you need to have at least one more data point than the order of the fit - if so this is more of a signal processing question than a code question.  Did you try a spline order of two?

Comment: hi. Thanks for the reply. Yes i have tried with even 5 data points but still the same problem. I am very new so not much sure at the moment. i am able to plot my data correctly if i do not use spline option. So i dont understand why. You can see my first (left plot) , that is good and its exactly same as in excel. Just get problem when try to make it spline

Comment: If all you want to do is smooth your data and you don't necessarily need a spline, you could use Numpy's [polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit) to *create a polynomial* for the data and use [polyval](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval) to evaluate it at the new *x* points.